# OpenGLES2: How to load and access a big float array

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a large WxH float array:

```
float floatArray[W][H];
```

I want to access it in a fragment shader and I need to load/access it through a texture due to its size:

```
vec4 v4 = texture2D(tex, v_texCoord);
//Getting v4.x as floatArray[v_texCoord.x * W][v_texCoord.y * H]
```

I load the texture like this:

```
int texturenames[1];
glGenTextures(1, texturenames);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texturenames[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, w, h, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, floatArray);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program_, "tex"), texturenames[0]);
```

I don't get the right values. Note that the third (internalformat) and seventh (format) parameters of [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) are GL_LUMINANCE.

```
void glTexImage2D(GLenum target,
GLint level,
GLint internalformat,
GLsizei width,
GLsizei height,
GLint border,
GLenum format,
GLenum type,
const GLvoid * data);
```

How can I load and access a big float array in OpenGLES2?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't. OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support floating point texturing.

Given you only want a single channel perhaps you could encode it in an RGBA unorm texture and recover the value algorithmically in the shader, but it sounds horribly expensive on a mobile GPU.

OpenGL ES 3.0 does support float texturing, so that might provide more luck.